# Update item in objects array based on object property

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an array of objects with the below structure, how can I update the object's data (`file`) based on one of the object property (`name`)?
for example how can I update the object named: `test1` with a new `file` object?

I have tried that but the correct object isn't being updated, a new object is being pushed to the array instead, what am I doing wrong?

```
const [files, setFiles] = useState(fileArr)

const setFile = (name, data) => {
  setFiles(files => ({...files, [name]: {...files[name], ...data}}))
}
```

`fileArr` array:

```
const fileArr= [
  {
    name: 'test1',
    status: 'Required',
    file: {}
  },
  {
    name: 'test2',
    status: 'Required',
    file: {}
  },
  {
    name: 'test3',
    status: 'Required',
    file: {}
  }
]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the following structure

```
const fileArr= [
  {
    name: 'test1',
    status: 'Required',
    file: {}
  },
  {
    name: 'test2',
    status: 'Required',
    file: {}
  },
  {
    name: 'test3',
    status: 'Required',
    file: {}
  }
]
```

The correct way of updating an object based on `name` to replace `file` is

```
const onChange = (name, data) =>{
    setItems(items => items.map(item =>{
        if(item.name === name)
            //assuming you want to spread instead of overwrite 'file'
            return {...item, file:{...item.file, ...data}}

        return item
    }))
}
```

Also you're initializing your state with `fileList` which based on how you're trying to update is an `object`, but you posted `fileArr` as your data structure. So I'm assuming that you want to perform your operations in `fileArr` instead of `fileList` (which I don't know how it's look like)